# Censor text with regex

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I'm currently running this command to censor an indented to-do list.

```
sed -e 's/\(\s\+- \)\(.*\)/\1XXX/g'
```

It's great except that I'd like the number of `X`s to match the number of matched characters. How do I do that? The correct way doesn't especially need to use sed.

Current example input:

```
- Hello World
  - Earth
```

Output:

```
- XXX
  - XXX
```

Desired:

```
- XXXXXXXXXX
  - XXXXX
```

Comment: `Hello World` is 10 non-whitespace characters. I would be fine with solutions that output either 10 `X` or 11 `X`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 's/^( *- )(.+)/$1."X"x length($2)/e'
```

This uses `"X" x length($2)` to get the correct number of `X`s in the replacement.

Test input:

```
- Hello World
  - Earth
This is not - censored
```

output:

```
- XXXXXXXXXXX
  - XXXXX
This is not - censored
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `sed` too:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]/{
h
s///
s/./X/g
x
s/\([[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]\).*/\1/
G
s/\n//
}' infile
```

This copies the line over the `h`old buffer, removes the first part `[[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]`, replaces the remaining characters with an `X`, then e`x`changes pattern/hold space so now the censored string is in the hold pattern and the original line is back into the pattern space. The second part of the line is removed with `s/\(...\).*//`, the string in the hold space is appended to pattern space (`G`) and the `\n`ewline char is removed. So with a file like:

```
- line here
not - to be modified
  - a b c d e
 - another line-here
```

the output is:

```
- XXXXXXXXX
not - to be modified
  - XXXXXXXXX
 - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

If you want to remove blank chars and replace only the non-blank ones with `X`:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]/{
h
s///
s/[[:blank:]]//g
s/./X/g
x
s/\([[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]\).*/\1/
G
s/\n//
}' infile
```

output:

```
- XXXXXXXX
not - to be modified
  - XXXXX
 - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

or, in one line with `gnu sed`:

```
sed -E '/^[ \t]*-[ \t]/{h;s///;s/[ \t]//g;s/./X/g;x;s/([ \t]*-[ \t]).*/\1/;G;s/\n//}' infile
```

---

Adjust the regex (i.e. `^[[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]`) as per your needs.

Comment: Man, this taught me new things about sed, so I really appreciate it. I'm going to give the perl answer the solution since it's like one line but wow.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/^[ ]*- /{gsub(/[^ -]/,"X",$0)}1' <<EOM
- Hello
  - World 2015
This is not - censored
EOM

- XXXXX
  - XXXXX XXXX
This is not - censored
```

The `awk` expression looks for any lines that begins with a `-` character, after optional whitespaces. For matching lines, the `gsub()` command replaces all characters except for whitespaces and the `-` character. The final `1` is just a shortcut for `{print $0}`, i.e. to re-print the entire line.

**edit**: Since you also require removing/replacing the whitespace characters with `X` too, I can't really think of a more elegant solution other than to do an additional replacement:

```
$ awk '/^[ ]*- /{gsub(/[^ -]/,"X",$0);gsub(/X X/,"XXX",$0)}1' <<EOM
- Hello World
  - Earth
This is not - censored
EOM

- XXXXXXXXXXX
  - XXXXX
This is not - censored
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was a terrible example on my part, I apologize. Let me amend my example. I'm looking for something without the spaces on the right, or I would know how to do it. But I'm not sure how to do what I'm looking for without lookaround.

Comment: @ZacharyVance see edited answer... I know it's probably still not what you're looking for, but at least it's not a completely wrong answer now...

Comment: This is what I was trying. It fails when there's single-letter words because substitutions can't overlap.

Answer (score 2):

To replace all alphanumeric characters with `X`:

```
$ tr '[:alnum:]' 'X' <file
- XXXXX XXXXX
  - XXXXX
```

To fill in the spaces between words:

```
$ tr '[:alnum:]' 'X' <file | sed 's/X X/XXX/g'
- XXXXXXXXXXX
  - XXXXX
```

Or, using only `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/[[:alnum:]]/X/g; s/X X/XXX/g' file
- XXXXXXXXXXX
  - XXXXX
```

Using `sed` as above, but also restrict the modification to lines that starts with a dash, preceded by optional spaces and/or tabs:

```
$ sed '/^[[:blank:]]*-/ { s/[[:alnum:]]/X/g; s/X X/XXX/g; }' file
- XXXXXXXXXXX
  - XXXXX
```

You may notice that the filling in of spaces only works when there are no single letter words in the data.  A string like `This is a tree` would be converted into `XXXXXXXXX XXXX`.  To avoid this, you may do a simple loop:

```
sed -e '/^[[:blank:]]*-/ { s/[[:alnum:]]/X/g; :again' \
    -e 's/X X/XXX/g; t again' -e '}' file
```

This performs the second substitution and then jump back to the `again` label if that substitution actually changed something.

Or, simpler, but would miss a trailing space character:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*-/ { s/[[:alnum:]]/X/g; s/X /XX/g; }' file
```

Comment: The last command would fill in space followed by non-word.  Did you mean `s/X \b/XX/g`?

Comment: @TobySpeight Definitely not! Since the user is not talking about "words" in the question, I'm assuming all characters should be X-ed out, no matter whether they are word characters or otherwise.

Comment: But your code doesn't do that - only word characters and the first space after each word.  I think you need to split the line, storing the prefix in the hold space, and substitute everything in the pattern space before rejoining.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, I see what you mean now. Thanks. I will revisit this at some later time.

Comment: Also: echo "- note a problem" | tr '[:alnum:]' 'X' | sed 's/X X/XXX/g' outputs `- XXXXXX XXXXXXX`

Answer (score 0):

if the spaces in the mentioned lines not important you could use the below line

```
Q='Some things\n - Hellow World\n   - Earth\nSome things Else'
echo -e "$Q" | awk '{ if ($0 ~ /^\s+-\s\w+/) print system("echo " $0 "| tr [:alnum:] x "); else print $0; }'  | grep -v ^0$
```

> `$0 ~ /^\s+-\s\w+/` check regex as you mentioned.
>
> `system(...)` run **Bash** command inside `awk`
>
> `grep -v ^0$` this part because `system(...)` return *exit code status*.

we could get rid of *grep -v ^0$* part with `getline` **I/O statements** but it is more complicated.